# Allow only special characters except space in textbox

Tags: javascript, validation

I have an input textfield for which some validations are applied. the user cannot enter numbers and special characters in the field. everything is fine but i want to allow space in between the words. how to do it.

Here is the code...

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onKeyPress="return IsAlpha(event);"/>

        var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
     specialKeys.push(32); //Tab
    specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
    specialKeys.push(36); //Home
    specialKeys.push(35); //End
    specialKeys.push(37); //Left
    specialKeys.push(39); //Right
    function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you can do like this using Regex:

```
$('.test').keyup(function() {

     var $th = $(this);

     $th.val( $th.val().replace(/[^0-9' ]+( [0-9' ]+)*$/g, function(str) 
      {  

       return ''; 

      } 

     ));

});
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wAJSR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

best way using regex Pattern

```
 var patternforchar=/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
 $("#text1").bind('keyup',function(){

       if(patternforchar.test($(this).val())){
         alert("highlight your error");
        return "false";//do form submit error
       }else{ return "true"}

  });
```